# pip install mitmproxy egg_info error 1

Tags: python

When I try to install `mitmproxy` via `pip install mitmproxy` I get this error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-7emirj\netlib

I'm running windows 8.1 and python 2.7.10. Setuptools and distribute are both installed and up to date. How do I fix this and does it have something to do with stuff not being in my `PATH`? I have confirmed that the Python directory is in the `PATH`

Comment: Is there any more output in the error message? I would expect some additional error messages

Comment: No that's all. It just shows up after it tries to download it

Comment: FWIW, we just pushed a new release which should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems mitmproxy requires python 3 and pip3, I just fixed this on Debian. I've installed many dependencies required by it, including pip3 so after all dependencies you'd type `pip3 install mitmproxy` and it should work. The dependencies are listed in the link below, I also had to add `pip3 install cryptography`.

Their site has good resources for installation and what to type depending on the platform: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/install.html#advanced-installation

The last error I'm running into is mitm is being run by python 2.7, not 3.5. You can figure out which version is running by typing `python`, then `help()` and it will be at the top of the prompt.